# Qt: Roundoff of 12.625 by 2 returns 12.62

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, rounding-error

I can't get it why the ff code **returns 12.62 instead of 12.63**

```
 QDebug << QString::number(12.625, 'f', 2);
```

and also what will be the solution for this? Currently my solution is this

```
QDebug << QString::number(12.625 + 0.0001, 'f', 2);
```

and it will return `12.63`.

btw my OS is ubuntu 11.04

Comment: `printf("%.2f", 12.625);` prints `12.62` on my machine, using gcc 4.8.2. I suspect it's got to do with floating point precision.

Comment: [12.625](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=049050046054050053) can be represented exactly in binary floating-point types so I think it's the printing problem

Answer (score 0):

GCC uses "Round to Even" or "Banker's Rounding" as it's default mode while Visual Studio uses "Round away from Zero"

From the GCC docs: [Rounding](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Rounding.html)

> This is the default mode. It should be used unless there is a specific
>   need for one of the others. In this mode results are rounded to the
>   nearest representable value. If the result is midway between two
>   representable values, the even representable is chosen. Even here
>   means the lowest-order bit is zero. This rounding mode prevents
>   statistical bias and guarantees numeric stability: round-off errors in
>   a lengthy calculation will remain smaller than half of FLT_EPSILON.

To change the rounding mode, use `fesetround(FE_UPWARD)` to round upwards. If you aren't using GCC, your compiler will have a similar option.

Rick Regan provides a list of programming environments and their default rounding behaviours. [Inconsistent Rounding](http://www.exploringbinary.com/inconsistent-rounding-of-printed-floating-point-numbers/)

Comment: So this is the reason, but to fix it I need to modify the compiler right? It is complicated to me I think. Is there other way of coding or alternative to fix it?

Comment: it's the printing function of Qt, not the compiler

Answer (score 0):

There is an open bug report for this:

https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-38171